# Naming classes in C#(or any other language)

Tags: c#, class, naming-conventions

I often have this kind of situation - there's a simple plain class, say, Article. And there's another class which stores all articles and meta information about them. I usually name it ArticlesManager. But I've read that this is a bad practice to have such words as Manager, Class in class name. So, how should we call it and how should we call its namespace if Article class is in Models namespace?

Comment: Where did you read that? The name isn't as important as what's actually in the class. If you have a class that needs a name like that then perhaps it indicates bad practice in the design of the class itself?

Comment: How about `Magazine` =) Or `ArticleRepository`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about naming it (as you did in your question) ArticleMeta?

Comment: Its like hand grenades -- the shortest name or suffix that comes within ten yards of being descriptive of the reality is best. Which reminds me to google 'three letter words' and pick out which may work for coding conventions.

Answer (score 2):

The big disadvantage of calling something "manager" is that the class tends to take on too many responsibilities after that and start violating the single responsibility principle.

Think for example of a class handling storing the articles in a database and naming the class "ArticleStore" versus naming it "ArticleManager". When the next programmer needs a place to do translations of articles, which of the classes is more likely to end up with that unrelated code?

This does not mean calling something "ArticleManager" is a no-no if it *actually makes sense* as a name of what the class does, it just means that it's a very generic name and trying to narrow the name to what the class actually does is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Short of it: if ArticleManager gives better descriptive understanding than anything else you can think of, just call it ArticleManager.

Long of it:   firstly, you should architect your solution properly.  if, after that, your class is best described as "ArticleManager" then by golly, callit ArticleManager.  don't get stuck on naming conventions.  Conventions are there as rules-of-thumb, meant to be adapted (or ignored) if there is a logical (and well thought out) reason.

My own example: in .net you are "not supposed to make variables public" which is correct 99% of the time.  The 1% of the time it's not correct is if using properties has a measurable performance penalty over naked variables.